# unity drag & drop files to another window

Tags: unity, drag-and-drop

For example: i have 2 nautilus windows opened and maximized and i want to move a file from window A to window B.
If i drag the file on the unity launcher it doesn't move the file but it will open the window where files is -.-''
I'm doing something wrong or there are a **big** bug into unity??
Thanks


PS: i'm using Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, obviously packages are up-to-date ;)

Answer (score 6):

try with:

1. Start dragging the file
2. Press and hold Super (windows key) + Tab (do not release the mouse button)
3. Hold Super and press Tab as many time you need to choose your file window destination
4. Release Super when you have selected the correct window
5. Release mouse button to drop the file

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal can you do only the steps 2, 3 and 4??

Comment: @inye i start dragging file and followed ur instruction when i drop file in drop area, then nothing happen :(

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal from and to what application you need to move?

Comment: i am developing a drag and drop module in php so i start dragging photo and try to put in on my page but nothing happen

Comment: i also try to drop in gmail.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal and what happend if you put the source app in the left side of the screen (ctrl+super+left_arrow) and de destination app in the right side (ctrl+super+right_arrow) and try to drag and drop??

Comment: I didn't try like this,let me try

Answer (score 4):

There is a user on launchpad that found a great workaround. Use the scale plugin assigning it to one of the screen corners, it works great I would say:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/995039/comments/5

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I just did it on Unity **3.8.16** in Ubuntu 11.04 and it worked fine, but not in Ubuntu 12.04. Sounds like a regression to me!

Could not find anything on this bug, so I reported it on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/995039

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do this, but you can use F3 to open "two panel" nautilus and drag and drop files this way.

Comment: No bug, you're trying to do something that can't be done unless you do as Jiri suggested or un max the windows

Comment: It's not a bug, doug, but it's a regression as it is something that was possible before (namely, in gnome).

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to dnd files from nautilus to Google Drive, will check it out with other programs. In Chrome, sign in to Google Drive. Create an Application Shortcut (Tools, Create Application Shortcut). Make the Application Shortcut screen you just created "Always on Top." Launch nautilus. In Nautilus, select the file or folder you want to dnd into Drive. DND the file or folder to the Drive window (when the cursor is in the correct area of the Drive window, you will see the plus ( + ) sign on the file or folder you are dnd'ing. Drop the file or folder and you should be good to go.

Will see if I can do this without having to actually make an Application Shortcut to Drive.

Comment: Okay, so you don't actually need to create an Application Shortcut. Simply minimize the window of the program to which you want to drag the files, mark the window as "always on top," drag files from, say, Nautilus. Works for Google Drive, Gmail, etc. For example, you can Compose a gmail and drag multiple files to attach them. Strongly agree that you should be able to do same with Unity, but this works just as well and is not that much slower, though it is considerably less elegant than it would be to simply drag to the launcher.