# Drag-drop between windows

Tags: 12.04, window, drag-and-drop

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 TLS.

Is it possible to drag-and-drop items between windows using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

For example, I'm in a folder and want to drag a file onto google chrome, where I have drive.google.com opened in one of the tabs.
So I click on the file, and while I'm still clicking I try to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (as I'd do in MS Windows), but the window choosing bar isn't shown.

Comment: possible duplicated 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/123948/unity-drag-drop-files-to-another-window

Answer (score 1):

nope Alt+Tab won't work if you hold your left mouse button

instead try draging the file or folder on to the icon of the application present at the  left of the screen (if you are using unity)

Comment: Oh, too bad. Although using unity, for some reason I can drag the file only on to emacs (that's the only "enabled" icon). Any idea why's that?