# drag and drop does not work in yahoo webmail mail

Tags: 14.04, email, drag-and-drop, yahoo

I'm trying to attach files to a yahoo email (web mail) by dragging and dropping on Ubuntu 14.04 with Firefox. When I drag the file over the email it highlights (turns green) and displays a message to "drag and drop attachment here", but when I release the file it doesn't attach.

Has anyone figured out the drag and drop attachment issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this https://askubuntu.com/a/393070/163693

In resumen

1. Start dragging the file
2. Press and hold Super (windows key) + Tab (do not release the mouse button)
3. Hold Super and press Tab as many time you need to choose your file window destination
4. Release Super when you have selected the correct window
5. Release mouse button to drop the file